# How to pass a list of arguments to Argo Workflows and accept it via argument parser

Tags: python-3.x, list, command-line-arguments, argparse, argo-workflows

I am new to Argo Workflows. I am trying to pass a list of argument as parameter to Argo workflow. The workflow should take this list of argument via argument parser.But when i check the values inside pod,it is not parsing correctly. Can some one please help me.

Sample Python code

And argo workflow should take this parameter as:

`argo submit --watch -n argo examples/workflow-input-list.yaml -p my_list='["foo", "bar", "baz"]'`

Output in the pod

`['["foo", "bar", "baz"]']`  what we need is `["foo", "bar", "baz"]`

Comment: `import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--my_list', nargs='+', type=str, help='List of strings')
args = parser.parse_args()
my_list = args.my_list
print(my_list)`

Comment: It's hard to read code that gets smushed together in a comment.